# LibGDX + Kryonet, will it work on iOS?

Tags: ios, networking, libgdx, kryonet

I'm creating a multiplayer mobile game using LibGDX library. For networking I use Kryonet which is written in Java. As I read (and tried), Kryonet works well on Android devices but I have no emulator/device to test anything on iOS.

Did anyone tried this and has it any chance to work?

Comment: Did you happen to find out? im asking myself the same question

Comment: I didn't try, but I think it should work. The entire java code gets recompiled, along with Kryonet. Issues with these kind of things is that in order to test it, you need a Mac to deploy LOL.

Comment: + as from Nathan's comment here: https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet/issues/54 - it will work with LibGDX. He's an author of kryo and gdx.